# How can I give control to my own login page/app in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a private app to manage the user log in into windows phone device. I assume my app should run by the phone OS after boot operation finished and the OS should give the control to my app to manage the log in process through my app instead of build in process if any and the user might pass my app log in first to access the phone apps and content.

How do I update, set the phone OS/ manifest/  boot file , what ever the item should be updated to give my app the control over phone access is, using c# through visual studio 2012 for windows phone 8?

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, by intentional Microsoft design, do any of the features you requested in any documented/standard way on a Windows Phone.

Also, while it may be possible as an OEM working closely with Microsoft on specific hardware/software implementation, it's not something that is generally available, and would not be an application that you could distribute.

If you want to gain deep access to the operating system, Android is likely the most open in that regard to being able to completely control the experience.